# change windows language by dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I have some textFields and want to change the language input when the user came to write its data. In my example, I want the user to write his/her name in two different languages. so it's not friendly to change each time when the user wants to write the name, I want to when the textField got focus, automatically system input language changes the language to the one which the field is for.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not possible in flutter, this issue is still open**

Visit the Issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25841

but you can achieve this by using package available on flutter pub.dev
https://pub.dev/packages/virtual_keyboard_multi_language